Propagating a function using spherical harmonics?
Say I have the unit sphere (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) $S$ and some compact subdomain of it $D$. Assume I have a function $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.
The goal is to propagate $f$ to all of $S$, such that the extended function $g: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is equal to $f$ over $D$ and is "similar" to $f$ outside of $S$. By "similar" I mean it exhibits some kind of "periodicity". for example if $f$ has 3 local maxima, then this feature should be propagated to the regions outside of $D$ in a proportional manner.
e.g. $f$ has 3 local maxima, $D$ is roughly 1/5 of the area of $S$, then the propagated function $g$ should have roughly 15 (as in $3 \times 5$) local maxima as uniformly distributed as possible over the surface of $S$. And the same would be true for other features such as local minima.
